# Android BLE often disconnect (bluetooth 4.0)

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, hardware, disconnect

I am having problems on BLE development.

When testing on my own old cellphone which android API is 19, it's ok and nothing is wrong, but on the other cellphone which android API is 23 the BLE will disconnect after about 2 min and 30 sec and I don't know why.

The rate of the data sent by the bluetooth is about 80HZ, I know it may be too fast for the BLE but we actually need it.

We notice that if the Bluetooth agreement on the cellphone is not 4.0 but 4.1 or higher the disconnecting problem will happen.

Comment: I would say the only thing to debug this his using an air sniffer if the disconnect reason is Connection Timeout (0x08).